How to make diagnostic of a gam full model averaged?
I want to know which variables have a significant effect on my response variable (11 variables in a gam model with some smoothed terms).
I used the function dredge in the packaged MuMIn, and my weights are so low: when I use subset=cumsum(weight)<=.95, I get 72 models with weights between 0.03 et 0.01 and 115 models with weights = 0.00... Therefore, I am looking at the Model-averaged coefficients (full average) to see what is significant.

Should I actually use subset=cumsum(weight)<=.95 or subset=delta < something ? (weights = 0.00 when delta AIC = 3.63)

How to make diagnostic of my full model averaged? DHARMa does not work with model avg ... Do I have to use DHARMa with each one of these? Or is there a better solution?


